# How can I find what data is clustering in K-Shape?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote codes,

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tslearn.clustering import KShape
from tslearn.datasets import CachedDatasets
from tslearn.preprocessing import TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance


ks = KShape(n_clusters=3, n_init=10, verbose=True, random_state=seed)
y_pred = ks.fit_predict(data)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
for yi in range(3):
    plt.subplot(3, 1, 1 + yi)
    for xx in stack_data[y_pred == yi]:
        plt.plot(xx.ravel(), "k-", alpha=.2)
    plt.title("Cluster %d" % (yi + 1))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I want to divide `data` by usigng KShape’s clustering.Now plot is shown, but I cannot find what data is in each 3 clustering.

data is an order of A,B,C,D ’s kind.So I want to show label to plot or the result of the clustering.I searched KShape’s document  (http://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_kshape.html ),but I cannot find the information to do my ideal things.How should I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why there are no perfect solutions

K-Shape works randomly, and without setting a seed for every iteration you might get different clusters and centroids. There is no deterministic way to know a-priori if a given class is completely described by a given centroid, but you can proceed in an offline fashion, in a fuzzy way, by checking to which centroid a given class is classified mostly.

Also any given class, `A` for instance, could contain elements that are part of two clusters in the space of the features you are considering.

Suppose you have 3 classes but your dataset is best described (for example by maximal average density) by 4 clusters: you'd surely have some points of at least one class that go in the 4th cluster.

Or alternatively, suppose your classes do not overlap with the centroids generated by the distance metric you are considering: take in consideration an obvious example: you have 3 classes, numbers from 0 to 100, from 100 to 1000 and from 1000 to 1100, but your dataset contains numbers from 0 to 150 and from 950 to 1100: a clustering algorithm would find its optimum with 2 clusters and put the points of class A in either one of the two.

Once you have determined that, for example, class `A` goes mostly to cluster `1`, class `B` to cluster `2` etc... you can proceed to assign that cluster to the given class.

## A possible fuzzy approach

We will proceed to determining the clusters classes by assigning the best fitted class to the cluster that contains most of its points:

### Simple example: classes that actually fit clusters

For this example we use one of [`tslearn.datasets`](http://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gen_modules/datasets/tslearn.datasets.CachedDatasets.html). This code is partially taken from [this K-Shape example on tslearn](http://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_kshape.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tslearn.clustering import KShape
from tslearn.datasets import CachedDatasets
from tslearn.preprocessing import TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance
from seaborn import heatmap
```

We set the seed, for code reproducibility:

```
seed = 0
np.random.seed(seed)
```

Firstly we prepare the dataset, selecting the first `classes_number=3` classes:

```
classes_number = 3
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = CachedDatasets().load_dataset("Trace")
mask = y_train <= classes_number
X_train, y_train = X_train[mask], y_train[mask]  # Keep first 3 classes
X_train = TimeSeriesScalerMeanVariance().fit_transform(X_train)  # Keep only 50 time series
sz = X_train.shape[1]
```

Now we find the clusters, with `clusters_number=3`:

```
# Euclidean k-means
clusters_number = 3
ks = KShape(n_clusters=clusters_number, verbose=False, random_state=seed)
y_pred = ks.fit_predict(X_train)
```

We now proceed to count the elements of each class that are assigned to each cluster and to add the 0 paddings for where no elements of a given class was assigned to a given cluster (*surely there will be a more pythonic way to d this but I've yet to find it*):

```
data = [np.unique(y_pred[y_train==i+1], return_counts=True) for i in range(classes_number)]

>>>[(array([2]), array([26])),
    (array([0]), array([21])),
    (array([1]), array([22]))]
```

Adding the padding:

```
padded_data = np.array([[
    data[j][1][data[j][0] == i][0] if np.any(data[j][0] == i) else 0
    for i in range(clusters_number)
] for j in range(classes_number)])

>>> array([[ 0,  0, 26],
           [21,  0,  0],
           [ 0, 22,  0]])
```

Normalising the obtained matrix:

```
normalized_data = padded_data / np.sum(padded_data, axis=-1)[:, np.newaxis]

>>> array([[0., 0., 1.],
          [1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 1., 0.]])
```

We can visualise the obtained matrix using [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
xticklabels = ["Cluster n. %s" % (1+i) for i in range(clusters_number)]
yticklabels = ["Class n. %s" % (1+i) for i in range(classes_number)]
heatmap(
    normalized_data,
    cbar=False,
    square=True,
    annot=True,
    cmap="YlGnBu",
    xticklabels=xticklabels,
    yticklabels=yticklabels)
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
```

Obtaining:

[image: Classes/clusters heatmap]

In this optimal situation, every cluster contains only and exactly one class, so with absolute precision we obtain:

```
classes_clusters = np.argmax(normalized_data, axis=1)

>>> array([2, 0, 1])
```

### Second example: classes that do not overlap with clusters

For simplicity sake, to simulate classes that do not overlap completely with the clusters I'm just going to shuffle part of the labels, but there a vast range of example: most of clustering problems ends up with classes that do not exactly coincide with a cluster.

```
tmp = y_train[:20]
np.random.shuffle(tmp)
y_train[:20] = tmp
```

Now, when we execute the script again we get quite a different matrix:

[image: Classes/clusters heatmap, non overlapping]

But we are still able to determine the classes clusters:

```
classes_clusters = np.argmax(normalized_data, axis=1)

>>> array([2, 0, 1])
```

### Third example: classes that do not exist in the dataset

Suppose we were lead to believe that in the dataset existed 4 classes: we would find after running with different values of `k` that the best number of clusters is `k=3` in our current dataset: how would we proceed to assign the classes to the clusters? Which class could be thrown away?

We proceed to simulate such a situation by arbitrarily assigning a forth class to our labels:

```
y_train[:20] = 4
```

Running again our script we would obtain:

[image: Classes/clusters heatmap, more classes than clusters]

Clearly the 4th class has got to go. We can proceed by thresholding on the mean variance:

```
threshold = np.mean(np.var(normalized_data, axis=1))

result = np.argmax(normalized_data[np.var(normalized_data, axis=1)>threshold], axis=1)
```

And we obtain yet again:

```
array([2, 0, 1])
```

I hope this explanation has cleared most of your doubts!

Comment: thank you for your answer.I cannot catch your sentence's  meaning from "Also a given class A could contain~~~".Would you show me example codes?

Comment: thank you for your writing.After reading your writing,Im little bit confused.After showing plot,a time series's graph is shown.Lines of the graph is connected with classes of A,B,C,D,isn't it?

Comment: Sure, but in the given case the classes are generated to fit with a cluster. Just set the number of cluster (that in the given example you know) to a different one and the phenomenon I'm describing will be clear. Anyway, code is on its way.

Comment: Updated the answer!

Comment: I can understand it very well!!Thank you so much!!